# What are the different network schemas for ISA server?

Tags: isa-server

Where can I read more about network schemas for ISA server? Maybe this is the wrong name as I'm translating from Spanish.

For example, there's the perimetal and the back-to-front, etc.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

ISA Server was replaced by [FF Threat Management Gateway](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/threat-management-gateway/en/us/default.aspx) (outgoing) and [FF Unified Access Gateway](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/unified-access-gateway/en/us/default.aspx) (incoming). If you're looking for [documentation on ISA 2006](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb898433.aspx), it's in the [Technet Library](http://technet.microsoft.com). Perhaps you can be more specific as to what you're looking for?

Comment: This sounds very interesting! What book do you recommend I buy to learn about this from the very beginning? I'd like to learn both outgoing and incoming. Thanks!

Comment: MS has books on [TMG](http://www.amazon.com/Deploying-Microsoft-Forefront-Management-Gateway/dp/0735649766/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1291129688&sr=8-4) and [UAG](http://www.amazon.com/Deploying-Microsoft-Forefront-Unified-Gateway/dp/0735649774/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1291129752&sr=8-1). Also the Technet Library has a lot of documentation, though it's mostly from a reference point of view.